# how to insert elements of matrix into cell array at indices specified by another column of the matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization, cell-array

I have a matrix `A` which is a `n` X 2 matrix of floats with the second column in each row representing the *column index* of the value in the first column. I would ideally like to vectorize the insertion of elements in the first column of `A` in the row `rowIndex` and their respective columns as specified by `A(:,2)`.

The pseudo-code for what I am looking to achieve is as follows:

```
myCellArray = cell(n X n)

%rowIndex is some predefined integer.
rowIndex
%A is my n X 2 matrix of values and corresponding column indices.
A
myCellArray{(rowIndex*ones(size(A(:,1),1),1)),A(:,2)} = A(:,1)
```

I have provided code for what I have tried at the bottom although I have tried something similar to the last line and it has failed hence I was wondering how something like this would work in MATLAB. Basically if my question is confusing, I am looking to vectorize insertion of elements into cell array by using a vector of indices and vector of values to insert at each index.

```
a{1,z(:,2)} = z(:,1)
```

Here I am trying to insert all values in the first column of `z` matrix into the cells indexed by 1 and the corresponding entry in the second column of `z` into the cell array.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
a(1,z(:,2)) = mat2cell(z(:,1), ones(1,size(z,1)), 1);
```

For example, with

```
z = [1 2
     3 4];
```

this results in

```
a = 
    []    [1]    []    [3]
```